# Why is dataWithPDFInsideRect from WebView not creating PDF with high quality on Mavericks?

Tags: html, macos, cocoa, pdf, webview

Run [sample project](https://github.com/tvarghese/TestWebView) and observe the output PDF generated on the Desktop named **SaveWebPage.pdf**

Pasting the snippet of code which is of interest

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Page" withExtension:@"html"];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[[self.webview mainFrame] loadRequest:req];
NSView *view = [[[self.webview mainFrame] frameView] documentView];
NSData *data = [view dataWithPDFInsideRect:[view bounds]];

NSArray* deskTopArrayPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDesktopDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* deskTopPath = [deskTopArrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* pdfPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/SaveWebPage.pdf",deskTopPath];

PDFDocument *doc = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithData:data];
[doc writeToFile:pdfPath];
```

**What the above code does?**

1. A WebView is used to load HTML which has PDF embedded in it using the **img** tags. See html source [here](https://github.com/tvarghese/TestWebView/blob/master/Page.html)
2. After loading the webview, trying to get PDF data from the document view using NSView’s **dataWithPDFInsideRect** method
3. PDF data in memory is written to disk

**Results**

- On Versions **before Mavericks (i.e 10.8 and 10.7)** the above snippet of code generated a PDF document which is of high quality with the contents readable. When output PDF is opened in Preview app, the PDF contents are seen rendered with high quality and on zooming the scaling takes place without compromise on image quality. [See Mountain Lion output PDF here](https://github.com/tvarghese/TestWebView/blob/master/TestWebView/SaveWebPage_MountainLion.pdf)
- On Mavericks (10.9), the above snippet of code generates a PDF document with its contents blurred with degraded image quality [See Mavericks output PDF here](https://github.com/tvarghese/TestWebView/blob/master/TestWebView/SaveWebPage_Mavericks.pdf)

**Questions**

1. Is dataWithPDFInsideRect: not working on Mavericks as it worked before on the previous versions of OSX?
2. Is there a change in the way I have to embed PDF’s in HTML (from Mavericks onwards) for Webkit to render them properly offscreen?
3. Is there an alternate way to obtain pdf from the same HTML to with better quality on Mavericks?

Answer (score -1):

PDF is a proprietary file format that Apple has purposely decided to not play well with for a variety of mostly corporate-political reasons.  The quality of the PDF you end up with entirely depends on the library you're using - and from the sound of it your latest Mavericks is using a different driver library which is less than ideal.

If you're rendering to HTML / using Webkit, there is a known issue with Mavericks wherein PDFs aren't handled by default properly by Safari.  To update this, run this command from your server terminal.

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKitOmitPDFSupport -bool NO
```

Downloading the latest copy of Adobe Reader & installing it may give you / re-install / refresh the proper drivers as well if this doesn't work.